# SQL Server 2008 - Strip numbers from start of string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008,

I have a table called locals which has records as follows:-

```
447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES
447456 -    12 ACACIA WALK
447457 -    13 ACTON HILL STUDIOS
447458 -    21 ADELAIDE COTTAGES
447459 -    321 ALBERT COTTAGES
456155 -    722 CLIVE COURT
```

What I want to do is remove all the numbers in the 'Street' column (maybe using REPLACE) so the records update to:-

```
447455 -   ABERCORN COTTAGES
447456  - ACACIA WALK
447457  - ACTON HILL STUDIOS
447458 -    ADELAIDE COTTAGES
447459 -    ALBERT COTTAGES
456155 -    CLIVE COURT
```

I have tried:-

```
UPDATE LOCALS 
SET Street = REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (str(50), '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', '') 
where AtoZIndex > '447454' 
  and AtoZIndex < '457309'
```

The street column is `NVARCHAR(50)`

But this just made all the records blank, any suggestions on how I could fix this?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: please help us help you... what are the fields in your table -- what are their types, where do these fields split in your example.  How did you get the output shown (is that a select statement?)  Without these answers there is NO WAY to answer your question.

Comment: Use `CHARINDEX` to find the space character (that separates the number and the text). Do a `SUBSTRING` using that to extract the text, following the position returned by `CHARINDEX`. Read the doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will truncate to the first alpha character:

```
UPDATE LOCALS SET 
    Street = SUBSTRING(Street, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', Street), LEN(Street))
WHERE
    AtoZIndex > '447454' and AtoZIndex < '457309'
```

Answer (score 2):

Hunt for the first `[A-Z]` character (assuming the non-number portion of the address starts in the range `A-Z`

```
select PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', '447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES')
15
```

Pick up the hyphen location

```
select PATINDEX('% - %', '447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES')
7
```

Pick up the leading numeric fragment

```
select SUBSTRING('447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES', 1,
PATINDEX('% - %', '447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES'))
447455
```

Pick up the text fragment of the address

```
select SUBSTRING('447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES', 
PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', '447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES'),
LEN('447455 -    1 ABERCORN COTTAGES'))
ABERCORN COTTAGES
```

Concatenate the fragments with a hyphen separator